# Python Selenium How to get the text value if no text or value attribute in the element

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I tried below ways to get the input field text value, but all of them were failed:

```
.get_attribute('value')
.text
.get_attribute('textcontent')
```

Here is the element:

```
<input placeholder="Name" type="text" formcontrolname="name" class="lmn-input ng-star-inserted ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid">
```

Here is the input box:
[image]

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve "John" then `elem.get_attribute("value")` is what you want.  I suspect that you are not correctly retrieving the WebElement representing the input field.

Answer (score 0):

There exists another method:

```
elem.get_text()
```